# Passing a parameter into Laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5

Building a blog platform and my goal is to stop a user from being able to directly access any pages that allow them to post under a different user.

For example, they have created a blog 'Blog 1'

If a different user goes to add a new post to that blog:

```
/blog/newupdate/1
```

Then I want to block that.

I have methods set up already for my user as I check it in the views, but need a way to block this access.

I have a middleware set up in a group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth','OwnsProject'], function () {
    Route::get('/project/newupdate/{id}',[
        'as' => 'project/newupdate',
        'uses' => 'ProjectController@createUpdate'
    ]);
});
```

In my middle ware I want to do:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::user()->ownsProject($id)) {
        // nada
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

But nothing seems to be coming through in the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **OwnsProject** middleware is not being applied to your route. If you are using 2 or more middleware, you must pass them in an array:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['auth','OwnsProject'] ], function () {
    Route::get('/project/newupdate/{id}',[
        'as' => 'project/newupdate',
        'uses' => 'ProjectController@createUpdate'
    ]);
});
```

As mentioned in Vishal's answer, this will return you the value of 'id' in your middleware.

```
$id = $request->route()->getParameter('id');
```

So you should do something like this in your middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $id = $request->route()->getParameter('id');

    if ( !( \Auth::user()->ownsProject($id) ) ) {
        return redirect('/'); // Or anything else you want
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access the `id` parameter using your request object as

`$id = $request->route()->getParameter('id');`

followed by your rest of the code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $id = $request->route()->getParameter('id');

    if (!Auth::user()->ownsProject($id)) {
        // nada
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: You can shorten this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `route` method on your request object.

```
$id = $request->route('id');
```

Comment: Route() returns null.

Comment: Show us what you're doing please?

Comment: dd($request->route()); // along with the other suggestions

Comment: You should pass a key in it

Comment: Yeah, both do not work / return null. Ill keep looking into it :)

Comment: Well, can you please take a look at the route method in Illuminate\Http\Request class there is a check if the first parameter is null and the it calls the get method on the router object. I am currently not at pc. :P I mean, there must be. Because I used it before. :D

Comment: I just realised that you can simply call the magic __get method by typing `$request->id` which calles the `route('id')` automatically if you don't have any `id` field in your request.